# How to Deploying a Containing App to Older Versions of iOS with iOS 8 extension

Tags: ios8, keyboard

I had develop keyboard extension for iphone app. But my app is also deployed in ios 7 too.
In the iOS 7 it is crash. I get solution from Apple doc but did not understand.[Deploying a Containing App to Older Versions of iOS](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCQQygQwAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fprerelease%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2FGeneral%2FConceptual%2FExtensibilityPG%2FExtensionScenarios.html%23%2F%2Fapple_ref%2Fdoc%2Fuid%2FTP40014214-CH21-SW3&ei=6YWuVIHAENK9uATXyoGgAw&usg=AFQjCNFtrq7svpMahC6ZxQwutgxeC2t_9Q&sig2=wmzYqj5DUXRIr8XnWbr7-Q)
Please Help to solve this.
Thanks.

Comment: How are you? __iOS developer.....__

Comment: Fine mr Android Developer @M D

Comment: Whats up budy? give me your skypeID